# How to find my local ip as given to me by my router?

Tags: networking, bash, ip

I know that I can get my local IP address as given to me by my router / switch via GUI through:

Network Settings > Clicking the Gear Icon on my connection > Details

[image: GUI view to see the local IP address]

I can see my local IPv4 addres is `192.168.0.33`.

Now I want to get that information via script, yet commands like `ifconfig` or `ip addr show` are not helpful as they spam a lot of needless information, esp. when I have a lot of docker networks up and running:

```
$ ifconfig 
br-22f8c9813546: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:6cff:fef9:ddd0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:6c:f9:dd:d0  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10391  bytes 15285773 (15.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 19709  bytes 2896606 (2.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-4ee9377a4fb8: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.27.255.255
        ether 02:42:ac:d2:0b:19  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-5d61846f1fe4: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.16.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.31.255
        ether 02:42:39:05:be:f5  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-63d1527ef2dd: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.23.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.23.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:b4ff:fe53:65fb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:b4:53:65:fb  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11  bytes 308 (308.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6308  bytes 1053677 (1.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-7f9030324082: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.24.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.24.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:f3ff:fef5:70f3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:f3:f5:70:f3  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 411  bytes 59490 (59.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7005  bytes 1115316 (1.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-ede87c785445: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.26.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.26.255.255
        ether 02:42:4f:6e:2b:ac  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:32ff:fe09:c11d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:32:09:c1:1d  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 141965  bytes 8102281 (8.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 489342  bytes 834915500 (834.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.33  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::1bf5:8c15:d648:f3a2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2a02:8108:41bf:c4b0:94ab:8d54:b734:1cb0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2a02:8108:41bf:c4b0::3c00  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2a02:8108:41bf:c4b0:d1bb:4aa7:7cce:b458  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 00:2b:67:55:f0:7e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8392238  bytes 7753304474 (7.7 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3495895  bytes 829060783 (829.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 435614  bytes 34898994 (34.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 435614  bytes 34898994 (34.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth21dba4f: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::70b7:7dff:fef6:1a08  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 72:b7:7d:f6:1a:08  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 93  bytes 12013 (12.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth2353f27: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::7caa:faff:fee1:1aa8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 7e:aa:fa:e1:1a:a8  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 106  bytes 13631 (13.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth6f6e69f: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::5f:eff:fead:28dd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:5f:0e:ad:28:dd  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 90  bytes 11699 (11.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth70fd5c3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::6c48:28ff:feed:5680  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 6e:48:28:ed:56:80  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 92  bytes 11959 (11.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth78edec0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::98a5:e8ff:fe5b:a00  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 9a:a5:e8:5b:0a:00  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 90  bytes 11699 (11.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth82f3647: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::7021:5fff:fe12:b352  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 72:21:5f:12:b3:52  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 90  bytes 11699 (11.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethc53bf34: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::1816:e4ff:fe6b:a52f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 1a:16:e4:6b:a5:2f  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 106  bytes 13631 (13.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethff5b5ce: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::bc46:8eff:fe96:953f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether be:46:8e:96:95:3f  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 90  bytes 11699 (11.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.106  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::2c2e:15bf:db59:7079  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 80:30:49:50:7f:25  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 454632  bytes 104035107 (104.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 253268  bytes 36336390 (36.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The information is there hiding at:

```
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.33  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

yet I don't know how to properly filter for it. What is a more concise way to get my local ip address as given to me by my router / switch?

I want following output:

```
$ find-my-local-ip
192.168.0.33
```

Comment: Duplicate on unix & linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8518/how-to-get-my-own-ip-address-and-save-it-to-a-variable-in-a-shell-script

Answer (score 1):

As posted by [Bruno Bronosky on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/402160/12471):

```
 ip route get 8.8.8.8 | sed -n '/src/{s/.*src *\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p;q}'
```

is doing what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a python3 program to print the IP address of your computer. It will give you the IP of default interface and does not need any internet connection. This was originally given by fatal_error on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28950776/1525392)

```
import socket

def get_ip():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    try:
        # doesn't even have to be reachable
        s.connect(('10.255.255.255', 1))
        IP = s.getsockname()[0]
    except Exception:
        IP = '127.0.0.1'
    finally:
        s.close()
    return IP

print(get_ip())
```

Save this in a file named `get_ip.py` and run

```
python3 get_ip.py
```